# Error during table creation

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am trying to create a new table on a database but i am getting an error which says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'USERPRIVACYDB' does not exist.

The code is as follows:

```
public class UserPrivacyData {

    private static String password = null;
    private final static String USER = "root";
    final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/USERPRIVACYDB;create=true;";

    public void loadDB() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER); //load the driver
              connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USER, password);
      statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
String sql = "insert into USERPRIVACYDB values('" + gender[rand.nextInt(2)] + "',"
                    + " '" + privacyLevel[rand.nextInt(3)] + "', '" + age[rand.nextInt(3)] + "',"
                    + " '" + presentEducationLevel[rand.nextInt(3)] + "',"
                    + " '" + highestEducation[rand.nextInt(3)] + "', '"
                    + everVictimOfCrimeString + "', "
                    + " '" + crimeTypeString + "', "
                    + " '" + shareWithThirdParty[rand.nextInt(2)] + "',"
                    + " '" + reasonforChoiceofPrivacy[rand.nextInt(5)] + "')";

            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
           // }

        }

    }
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Where's your code demonstrating how you get this error message? Please read the [help]

Comment: Thanks Liam. The code is as follows:

Comment: public class UserPrivacyData {
    private static String password = null;
    private final static String USER = "root";
    final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/USERPRIVACYDB;create=true;";
        public void loadDB() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER); //load the driver
              connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USER, password);
   statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace(); }

Comment: `insert into USERPRIVACYDB` - there is no table with that name. You need to run a `create table insert into USERPRIVACYDB (...)` before you can use it. And _please_: learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Thanks a lot. i will explore your option. Though i thought the statement below automatically create such tables.

Comment: `insert` only creates new rows in an existing table. To be able to do that, you need to first create that table.

Comment: thanks all for the explicit explanation. Please can i know what this code is all about: final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/USERPRIVACYDB;create=true;";

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC Connection URL and JDBC driver class do not match:

```
final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/USERPRIVACYDB;create=true;";
```

A JDBC Connection URL of the form `jdbc:derby://hostname:port/path/to/db` is for use with the Client-Server configuration of Derby, so if you want to use this configuration, you'll need to change your driver to `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`, and place `derbyclient.jar` into your `CLASSPATH`.

The JDBC driver class `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` is for use with the Embedded configuration of Derby, so if you want to use this configuration, you'll need to change your JDBC Connection URL to `jdbc:derby:path/to/db`, and place `derby.jar` in your `CLASSPATH`.

This is probably not the entire problem with your code, but correcting it would be good, and would help you clarify your plans for how to build and deploy your application.

For more general background information about the basic Derby configurations, see: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/getstart/